# Mirgate asp.net website to godaddy

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-hosting

I have been tasked with migrating a website that was on our iis web server to Go Daddy. I am unfamiliar with asp.net an have a couple questions about migrating this site.

Included in the site files is a file called web.config with some connections strings.

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
         connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Followed by some security account. All the files for the site are straight HTML, jquery and css type stuff, except for a contact form that seems to be connected the database. My question is how likely is that this site will be easy to migrate. It runs on my local machine fine, except for the contact page.

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="Ellis.Website.Contact" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta content="IE=8" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
<title></title>

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- This is where you choose your color scheme - Just change the stylesheet name to the color you want. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/orange.css" type="text/css" />
<!-- You can choose from the following: red, orange, green, blue and violet. -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/superfish.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.7.3.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/coin-slider-styles.css" type="text/css" />

<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie7.css">
<![endif]-->

<!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jqFancyTransitions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/coin-slider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.tabs.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Delicious.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bluz.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="sub-page">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <!-- site-wrapper START here -->
<div id="site-wrapper">
  <!-- header START here -->
  <div id="header">
    <!-- container START here -->
    <div class="container">
      <!-- top START here -->
      <div id="top">
        <!-- logo START here -->
        <div id="logo">
          <h1><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="Ellis Storage" /></a></h1>
        </div>
        <!-- logo END here -->
        <!-- main-nav START here -->
                <div id="main-nav">
          <ul class="sf-menu">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>

            </li>
              <li><a href="locations.html">Locations</a>

            </li>

              <li><a href="staff.html">Staff</a>

            </li>

            <li><a href="tips.html">Moving Tips</a>

            </li>

            <li><a href="supplies.html">Moving Suppies</a>

            </li>

            <li class="current_page_item"><a href="contact.aspx">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- main-nav END here -->
      </div>
      <!-- top END here -->
      <div id="pagename">
        <h2><span>Contact Us</span></h2>
        <p class="tagline">When ever, where ever...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- container END here -->
  </div>
  <!-- header END here -->
  ""            ""
```

Answer (score 0):

How easy it is to migrate depends on your skill and experience, and how much of the site needs to be functional after you move it. 1:1 functionality? You must know the difference between windows hosting and other hosting, be familiar with backing up, migrating and restoring databases, database connection strings, bin folder, compiling the site, etc.

If some or all of the above are not in your experience, you may well have a difficult time :(

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have experience with web development and hosting basic websites. This type of site is new to me however. Never worked with asp.net. Although I am somewhat familiar with iis. The only thing that seems tricky will be this contact form. The rest is all HTML/CSS which I am familiar with.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I was able to take care of it as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Uploading the files worked as mentioned in this thread.